# Calculating timestamp in IE by jQuery - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, timestamp

I have some problem with IE (all versions). It don't calculating the code of timestamp. My code is below:

```
function compute() {
    var c = $('select#time_from_hour').val();
    var d = $('select#time_from_minute').val();
    var e = $('select#time_to_hour').val();
    var f = $('select#time_to_minute').val();
    var g = $('input#date_from').val();
    var h = $('input#date_to').val();
    var hour1 = g + ' ' + c + ':' + d; 
    var hour2 = h + ' ' + e + ':' + f; 

    hour1 = hour1.split("/"); 
    var hour1 = hour1[1] + "," + hour1[0] + "," + hour1[2];
    var timestamp = (new Date(hour1).getTime() / 1000) + 7200;
    $('#total_hour1').val(timestamp);

    hour2 = hour2.split("/"); 
    var hour2 = hour2[1] + "," + hour2[0] + "," + hour2[2];
    var timestamp = (new Date(hour2).getTime() / 1000) + 7200;
    $('#total_hour2').val(timestamp);

    var x = -$('input#total_hour1').val();
    var y = -$('input#total_hour2').val();
    var total_time = x - y; 
    result = total_time / 86400;
    new_number = Math.ceil(result); 

    if (isNaN(new_number)) { 
        var new_number = 0;
    }

    $('#finish_day').val(new_number);
}

$('select#time_from_hour').change(compute);
$('select#time_from_minute').change(compute);
$('select#time_to_hour').change(compute);
$('select#time_to_minute').change(compute);
// $('select#return_car').change(compute);
$('select#get_car').change(compute);
$('input#finish_day').change(compute);
```

On other modern browser (firefox, opera, chrome) everything works fine. Only on IE i got the "NaN" value in `timestamp1` and `timestamp2`.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please add the html also so that we can test.

Comment: here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/EbdFY/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to pass the Argument of the `Date`-Constructor in the wrong format. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dca21baa.aspx), the IE-Implementation of `Date` accepts the Date in the following order:

```
function Date( year : int, month : int, date : int[, hours : int [, minutes : int [, seconds : int [, ms : int]]]] )
```

If you make sure, that you pass the arguments in this format, everything should work fine. You'll find the working Code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/utXMD/

Comment: Thanks for the tip - there is only one more problem - below City 1 and city2 I got the fields "direction" and in IE i see all directions, and should see only 3 in direction no.1 and 3 in direction no.2 - on other browser everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem and able to run your code in IE too.

```
var hour1 = g + ' ' + c + ':' + d; 
var hour2 = h + ' ' + e + ':' + f; 

hour1 = hour1.split("/"); 
var hour1 = hour1[1] + "," + hour1[0] + "," + hour1[2];
var timestamp = (new Date(hour1).getTime() / 1000) + 7200;
```

No need to split the hour1, just pass the same to calculate the timestamp.
below code works

```
var hour1 = g + ' ' + c + ':' + d;
var hour2 = h + ' ' + e + ':' + f;

//    var hour1 = hour11.split("/");
//  hour1 = hour1[1]+","+hour1[0]+","+hour1[2];
var timestamp = (new Date(hour1).getTime()/1000) + 7200;
$('#total_hour1').val(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> function compute() {
>     var c = $('select#time_from_hour').val();
>     var d = $('select#time_from_minute').val();
>     var e = $('select#time_to_hour').val();
>     var f = $('select#time_to_minute').val();
>     var g = $('input#date_from').val();
>     var h = $('input#date_to').val();
>     var hour1 = g + ' ' + c + ':' + d;
>     var hour2 = h + ' ' + e + ':' + f; 
>
>     hour1 = hour1.split("/"); 
>     var hour1 = hour1[1] + "," + hour1[0] + "," + hour1[2];
```

Presumably the above results in a string something like:

```
day/month/year h:m:s
```

which is not guaranteed to be parsed correctly by any browser. In ECMA-262 ed 3 the parsing of date strings was entirely implementation dependent. In [ES5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15) a modified version of the ISO8601 format is specified but it's not supported by all browsers. And the above string isn't compliant with that format either.

```
>     var timestamp = (new Date(hour1).getTime() / 1000) + 7200;
```

That seems to be an attempt at creating a seconds since epoch number from a timestamp. It's better to use the bits of date and time you already have, something like:

```
// Presuming g is in the format day/month/year
g = g.split("/");
var someDate = new Date(+g[2], --g[1], +g[0], +c, +d + 2); // add 2 hours here
var timestamp = Math.round(someDate/1000);
```

I suggest you have a look at how the [Date constructor](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3) works and use it directly rather than trying to create a string that must them be parsed.